# Possible to access raw Javascript source from page?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Though Chrome extensions allow the access to a page DOM, I need to access the embedded Javascript source. I don't want to execute or even manipulate it, just want to generate a checksum. So - I wonder - is it even possible to access the script source - or for that matter - any other embedded content?

I have been able to access the DOM content, but it seems not to include the scripts from the page.

Comment: Embedded scripts can be accessed directly, remote scripts need to be downloaded from their URLs. Alternatively you can use chrome.debugger API to get the page snapshot and all of its scripts, [more info](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Page).